# Why did the portkey take Harry and the other Hogwarts contestant to Voldemort?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-goblet-of-fire

In **Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire** (2005), during the hedge maze, you must have quick reactions otherwise you can get taken out by sudden traps.

Both Harry and the other Hogwarts contestant are shown below:

[image: Harry and Cedric in the maze, small blue light in the background]

They have to run to make it to the portkey to avoid being swallowed by the maze walls.

The portkey, the blue light behind the two, is the one that took the two to Voldemort.

**Why did this portkey take the two to Voldemort when the other portkeys took  other contestants back to the start?**

Comment: Wasn't it said that Barty Crouch Jr. in Moody attire cursed it somehow? I don't remember exactly, though.

Comment: Which are these 'other' portkeys? There was only one Cup.

Comment: @bobbyalex: I get the feeling OP suspects that the traps themselves are portkeys (rather than dying, you end up back at the start). I can't confirm or deny that, but that's what I infer from his question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been discussed in [Why was the Triwizard cup portkey in Goblet of Fire two-way?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18134/70236) and [Why Did the Triwizard Portkey Return Harry to the Outer Edge of the Maze?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22996/70236).

In short, the portkey already contained the charm that would teleport the winner (the first person who touched it) to the beginning of the maze — this was by design of the tournament. Note that only one such portal existed, because there was only one cup, to be held by the only winner (Harry and Cedric weren't expected to touch it together).

It's possible that Barty Crouch Jr. couldn't remove that charm (or didn't bother to, or it'd alert someone), so he put the charm that teleported Cedric and Harry to the graveyard on top of the existing charm.

Thus we have two layers: the outer layer (put by Crouch Jr.) teleports you to the graveyard; the inner layer (by design of the tournament) teleports you to the beginning of the maze.

Comment: Cheers for the edit. @steelersquirrel ^_^

Comment: I think it's more Barty Crouch Jr. didn't bother to even try to remove the original teleport charm as he never expected anyone to come back to Hogwarts once they used it to go to the graveyard

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just for convenience of the movie, as it makes for a much more significant transition. Teleporting from a graveyard filled with Death Eaters and Lord Voldemort to a screaming and cheering crowd of his fellow classmates really helps to put the viewer (In my opinion) in a much better feeling of unease and discomfort to help show what Harry must be experiencing.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question, **why** did it take them there, what was there in the plot that took them there? Why did the portkey itself take them there? I don't really want to know about convenience to the crowd, I just want to know why that particular portkey took them to Voldemort directly.

Answer (score 1):

The other two contestants are injured/cursed during the last task. Harry and Cedric send up sparks to notify the judges/professors that there's an emergency. They were not portkeyed out of the maze.

As to WHY Harry is portkeyed to the Riddle estate, it's to use Harry in a ritual to give Voldemort a body since he was too weak before. (In the first book, he partially possesses Quirrell's body all year).